# How can I change the Xfce window manager to awesome?

Tags: xfce, window-manager, awesome

I'd like to use the Awesome Window Manager with all the other XFCE4 environment daemons, like keyrings, panels, power managers, etc. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Tested on Xubuntu 12.04, but with the ppas for Xfce 4.10 and 4.12 installed; however this will work from Xfce 4.8 onwards (default 12.04 version))

You can either run `awesome` as the window manager in an Xubuntu or Xfce session (which I think is what you want), or run it from its own `awesome` session (once installed that becomes an option in `lightdm`).

First install `awesome` from the repositories with

```
sudo apt-get install awesome
```

Now, if you want to run `awesome` as window manager in an Xfce or Xubuntu session, you can edit the relevant xfconf setting with:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command -t string -s "awesome" -a
```

This command changes the default window manager in the Xfce session to the `awesome` window manager. With **other** window managers such as `metacity`, you would instead use `-t string -s "metacity" -t string -s "--replace" -a` as the second part of the command. The `--replace` option is not available or needed anyway with `awesome`.

Now logout and login again by choosing the normal Xubuntu or Xfce session if you want to run `awesome` within an Xfce session.

To return to `xfwm4` as default window manager, run

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client0_Command -t string -s "xfwm4" -t string -s "--replace" -a
```

You may need to configure the various options in `awesome` by creating a personal rc file in `$HOME/.config/awesome` and tweaking the various options:

```
mkdir $HOME/.config/awesome
cp /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua $HOME/.config/awesome/
```

You will need to set up your themes and manually tweak how windows will appear, as the normal Xfwm4 window manager settings and tweaks will obviously not work when using `awesome`.

The screenshot below is of `awesome` running in a Xubuntu session, with the rest of Xfce still installed. If you have an Xfce panel at the top of the screen it will obscure the `awesome` panel, so you will have to move it elsewhere.

[image]

For more information on `awesome` and its keybindings, see `man awesome` and the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/awesome.1.html).

**Note:** This does not work at least as of Ubuntu 13.10. [Bug report](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10680) against XFCE4 opened.

Comment: I suspect something is changed, this does not work anymore. I see awesome panel for a second which is then overlapped by xfce4 panel. And everything hangs. Mouse works though.

Comment: In addition to the steps in the selected answer, you may also need to change the `/general/SessionName` property from `Default` to `Failsafe`. (Tested with switching to the i3 window manager in Xubuntu 14.04.)