# Error when copying from Desktop to any other location

Tags: nautilus, xubuntu, xfce

I recently installed Xubuntu and there were a lot of differences I noticed between xfce and gnome. I didn't like Thunar that much (mainly because of the searching feature - even catfish doesn't posses half of the capabilities Nautilus does). So I installed Nautilus and made it the preferred File Manager from exo-preferred-applications. At first everything seemed working - the searching function, places, bookmarks etc. However, I consequently tried copying a file from the Desktop to my home folder and the following error occurred:

[image]

And after pressing Skip, another one:

[image]

I tried uninstalling thunar and xfdesktop hoping that nautilus would 'take over' the desktop but that didn't happen. Also tried with a symlink for xfdesktop -> nautilus as suggested in some thread but that didn't do the trick either.

The error occurs whenever I try copying or moving something (a file or a folder) from the desktop to another location (by Ctrl+C or Copy from the context menu). Copying and moving works from and to other locations (even from a random location to the desktop but not from it). The strangest part is that when I drag and drop a file or folder from the Desktop to the desired location it works without any errors.

I would be grateful if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's an old post but might help you: [Xubuntu with Nautilus](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=98692).

Comment: Well, I don't know which version of Xfce is this tutorial for, but I can't seem to find almost half of the options and files mentioned. Thanks for the reply, though. Anybody else?

Answer (score 0):

The [article quoted above at Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=98692) is a very old discussion and is not really applicable to current Xfce. The following discussion is made up from my experimentation and with reference to the `nautilus --no-desktop` discussion at the [xfce forums](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=26298).

It depends whether you want to run `xfdesktop` and `nautilus` together, or let `xfdesktop` handle the desktop and use `nautilus` just as a filemanager. On my 12.04 machine, which has the ppas for xfce 4.10 and 4.12, `nautilus` seems to work well. However, there are some possibilities if you have problems.

I note you said that you had already made `nautilus` the default filemanager and removed `xfdesktop`, but you should be able to run `nautilus` and `xfdesktop` in the same session if you use the `--no-desktop` option when you run `nautilus`. If you apply any of the commands below, you should logout and then login again to see any changes.

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**  you must find what exactly are your own CLientCommands in your xfce session by launching xfce4-settings-editor and going to the `xfce4-session` tab and noting which ones currently refer to `Thunar` and `xfdesktop`, then modify the number in the commands below accordingly.

---

**Scenario 1**) no `xfdesktop` installed and `nautilus` is the default filemanager.

You may need to look at your `xfce4-session`, and alter the failsafe defaults for the Client Commands that define an Xfce session. You also have to do this if you wish to replace the window manager [with another one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169880/how-can-i-change-the-xfce-window-manager-to-awesome/281135#281135), and I think it might help in this case.

As an example, you could change the Client_Commands that refer to `Thunar` and `xfdesktop` to `nautilus --no-default-window` using `xfconf` (The `--no-default-window` option just stops a `nautilus` window being opened at login).

Remember to use the numbers of the Client_Commands on your own system-see `xfce4-settings-editor`.

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client2_Command -t string -s "nautilus" -t string -s "--no-default-window" -a
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client3_Command -t string -s "nautilus" -t string -s "--no-default-window" -a
```

Upon logging in you will get a blank desktop, but you can set a desktop wallpaper by using gnome applications such as `gthumb`.

This is the best way to ensure that `nautilus` is running the desktop and nothing else is interfering.

See the end of the article for how to reset them. Logout and login again to see any changes.

**Scenario 2)** `xfdesktop` is installed and you wish to use it to manage the desktop and `nautilus` as a filemanager.

Find the number of your own Client_Command for the filebrowser (Thunar) by refering to the `xfce4-session` part of `xfce4-settings-editor`. As an example, my Client_Command was 2, and so this was changed to `nautilus --no-desktop --no-default-window`.

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client2_Command -t string -s "nautilus" -t string -s "--no-desktop" -t string -s "--no-default-window" -a
```

Logout and login again to see any changes.
Remember to use the numbers of the Client_Commands on your own system-see `xfce4-settings-editor`.
Whenever you launch `nautilus` in your session you should use `nautilus --no-desktop`.

**If you need to Reset Changes**

Select the appropriate section in `xfce-session` in the graphical `xfce4-settings-editor` or use `xfconf-query`. You must use the actual numbers of the Client_Commands on your own system, not necessarily these ones given in the examples below:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client2_Command -t string -s "Thunar" -t string -s "--daemon" -a
xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /sessions/Failsafe/Client3_Command -t string -s "xfdesktop" -a
```

Logout and login again to see any changes.

The options suggested above might be useful for you, although very often problems with `nautilus` on Xubuntu are not always easily solved. The first scenario that makes `nautilus` manage the desktop and act as filemanager might be most useful, assuming you have made `nautilus` the default filemanager.

Comment: Well, I tried the commands @Mik suggested but the only thing that happened was that my panels disappeared and the error didn't. Am I supposed to alter my session from the Settings Manager or something else?

I tried launching nautilus with nautilus --no-desktop and while in terminal, copied a file from the desktop to another folder and the following error appeared in the terminal:

(nautilus:3560): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: @Abvgz The panels shouldn't disappear. Can you look in `xfce4-settings-editor` in the xfce-session part and tell me what Client2_Command and CLient3_Command refer to, as they should refer to filemanager and desktopmanager.

Comment: Um, could you please tell me where exactly are those because I couldn't seem to find them in 'Session and Startup'.

Comment: Launch `xfce4-settings-editor` in terminal and go to `xfce4-session`, and it will list the session defaults and the Client_Commands.

Comment: Client2_Command is nautilus --no-default-window and Client3_Command is the same. And by the way, xfce4-panel doesn't autostart when logging in now :(

Comment: @Abvgz it didn't affect xfce4-panel when I tested it as that should be Client1_Command. If you want to reset them you can click on the client command and click reset or use the commands at the end of the answer. Then logout and login again.

Comment: Well, my Client1_Command is xfsettingsd. Now when I reseted Client2_Command it changed to 'xfce4-panel' so that doesn't seem to be a problem anymore but the error when copying remains. What should I do?

Comment: @Abvgz I'll make an edit to the answer re how ClientCommands are sometimes numbered differently. If you reset all the ClientCommands and note which numbers (e.g. 3 and 4) refer to `Thunar` and `xfdesktop`, you could try the commands again but alter the number of the Client Command to match your system, then this time they would be applied to the right sections.

Comment: Due to the fact that I have xfdesktop installed and if I overwrite the Client4_Command with nautilus --no-default-window my desktop doesn't show up, I tried the command from the second scenario. I launched nautilus --no-desktop from terminal and copied a file but the error appeared again: (nautilus:4133): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: @Abvgz I'll research and test further and get back to you.

Comment: @Abvgz I think when you overwrote Client_Command 3 and 4 with `nautilus --no-default-window` and logged in again, that was indeed the best way to make sure `nautilus` takes over. Gnome programs such as `gthumb` can be used to set your desktop wallpaper.

Comment: I don't mind the wallpaper - I can certainly put up with a grey screen but the thing is that I can't see my Desktop items on the Desktop when I overwrite those command defaults. The folder is in its place but I can't right click on the desktop or copy any files to it - it's just grey and empty.

Comment: I edited ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus/preferences/%gconf.xml and now I can see my desktop wallpaper but I'm still not able to right click or see my desktop items. And in /etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop there's a line saying AutostartCondition=GSettings show-desktop-icons org.gnome.desktop.background so I thought it would show my desktop items but it doesn't. NoDisplay in this file is set to false now. Is there any way to fix the missing desktop items or even better for me - use xfdesktop and nautilus (with --no-desktop option) at the same time without an error when copying?

Comment: However, it seems that when the operating system boots the desktop is messed up, there isn't a wallpaper and whenever I place a window over it starts spreading across the screen and smudging it. Just as Windows XP back in the days :D When I log out and in that's fixed but the icons are still not visible.

Comment: @Abvgz Both scenarios listed allowed me to copy and paste files with Nautilus when I tested them, so I'm not sure what the reason of the copying error is.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your replies, Mik, I hope that someone else would help me. The pictures show the error encountered in the GUI and this is the error I receive in terminal: (nautilus:6081): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files Where 6081 is the process pid. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Just a little update - I just tried nautilus with the Live CD and the same error occurred! I use Raring Ringtail (13.04) and fear that this might be a problem of the distro. I am able to drag and drop the desired file or folder from the desktop to another folder without an error but it occurs when copying or cutting. By the way the nautilus Gtk-WARNING in terminal shows even when dragging and dropping.