# Xubuntu 13.04 + Xmonad alongside Xfce

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xmonad

Is it a possibility to run Xmonad with the menus etc from Xfce? Or is there any other tiling window manager that behaves in the same way but can retain the vanilla Xfce?

Comment: See [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169880/how-can-i-change-the-xfce-window-manager-to-awesome) for a way of changing the default window manager in a Xubuntu or Xfce session.